# Not able to find some of the gdal drivers when using the java bindings as opposed to gdal by itself

Tags: gdal, java, file-geodatabase

I am new to the gdal scene so there might be a simple explanation for my problem.  When executing ogrinfo from the command line there is a large list of supported formats.

```
    C:\OSGeo4W\bin>ogrinfo.exe --formats
    Supported Formats:
    "FileGDB" (read/write)
    "ESRI Shapefile" (read/write)
    "MapInfo File" (read/write)
    ...
```

However, when I run the equivalent command through the java bindings I get the following output:

```
    C:\OSGeo4W\bin>java -classpath ..\lib\gdal.jar;. ogrinfo --formats
    Supported Formats:
    "ESRI Shapefile" (read/write)
    "MapInfo File" (read/write)
    ...
```

Notice that the "FileGDB" driver doesn't appear when accessing gdal through the java bindings.  Why are some of the gdal drivers not available with the java bindings? Is it a problem with my classpath and some of the driver dlls locations?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` environment variable to the path of the gdal plugins folder. It's been a while since I've used osgeo4w, but the plugins folder is generally a folder inside of the bin folder where the gdal binaries can be found.

You may also want to set the `GDAL_DATA` variable as well, which should point to the folder containing all of GDAL projection (proj.4) files. This will allow OGR to reproject data.